# How to do multi site setup

Tags: customization, multisite

A client wants to set up a multi site with tabs looking like this:

| Home | About | Broker | Resources

On the main site (meaning www.site.com), the links will be www.site.com/home, www.site.com/about, etc.

Broker is a drop-down with Broker names that will be subdomains, like john.site.com. When the visitor clicks on an broker, and goes to the sudomain, they want all the tab links to be john.site.com/home, john.site.com/about, etc.

Obviously they don't want to have to copy all the posts and pages over to the each subdomain that are the throughout the site.

What is the best way of doing this?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to keep some pages common on all sub-sites? Please update your question with more details.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the Instruction on [Create A Network](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network).